# How to strip invisible 'hex c' character from us-ascii document that I cannot process in xslt

Tags: xslt, text, hex, ascii

I'm reading in a us-ascii document and trying to parse into XML

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="unparsed-text($filename,'us-ascii')" regex="{$regex_clp}">
```

However I'm getting the error

```
XTDE1190: The unparsed-text file contains a character that is illegal in XML (line=51 column=2 value=hex c)
```

In seeking to identify this character, I did a find and replace on all the visible character
and new lines and I'm left with a blank character in the document that causes the same error in a different position when executing the xslt script.

```
XTDE1190: The unparsed-text file contains a character that is illegal in XML (line=1 column=2 value=hex c)
```

When I copy and paste this 'hex c' into a java application attempting to strip it and then try to delete it with the backspace button it does not delete and rather I can push the backspace button multiple times and the cursor remains in the same position next to 'hex c' that I pasted.

I've uploaded this file here that has the 'hex c' character
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e0hkfraiSz39QEPV_zWn0ujyYcQknSCD/view?usp=sharing

Any idea what this character is and how to strip this character out of the file?

Regards
Conteh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after I posted the text file to google in creating this question, I download the out.txt just to make it still had the same problem after uploading and download from google.

However this time I could see a bunch of symbols in the text file. I copied them and into OxygenXML find and replace to see these were \f form feed

I found and replaced with \f and the problem was solved.

\f identifies (form feed, 0x0C).

Regards
Conteh